# How do I tell in code if the current process is a deployed version of my application?

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I have recently added an 'About' form to a project that's been around a while that I have recently taken control over.  As part of that I've made some changes, first to revamp the versioning, and second to implement it as a Click-Once deployment.

My question is:  How can I tell in the code if the application is running from a 'deployed version'?  Is this even possible?

I ask because I've got my deployment set to 'Automatically increment revision with each publish', and I want to reflect that in the About form.  To do so, I had to add the following code:

```vb
Try
        Me.LabelVersion.Text = String.Format("Version {0}", My.Application.Deployment.CurrentVersion.ToString)
Catch ex As Exception
        Me.LabelVersion.Text = String.Format("Version {0}", My.Application.Info.Version.ToString)
End Try
```

The deployment version doesn't work if it's ran through the devenv or just in a standalone copy that I manually setup.  For that I need the second with `Info.Version`.

I would rather not use a try-catch block here, it just seems messy.  However, I don't know how I would check for this in an if statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it seems I should have looked just a little harder before posting this question.  My Mistake.

This can be achieved by simply using `My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed`.

/Sigh